# CPU and Memory Stress in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, stress-testing, resource-management

I created a simple pod with resource limits. The expectation is that the pod gets evicted when it uses more memory than the limit specified. To test this, how do I artificially fill the pod memory? I can stress CPU with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null`, but not memory. Can someone help me with this please? I tried with stress utility, but no luck.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx     # Name of our pod  
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.7.1  # Image version
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 256Mi
      limits:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 256Mi
```

Comment: It should be fairly simple to write a small program in the programming language of your choice that keeps allocating memory. --- The pod will not get evicted, but `OOMKilled` by kubernetes.

Comment: I already did that. In that case, the command is getting exited with Killed, but the memory is not filling and pod is not getting killed.

Comment: @VasuYouth : Here you can find the steps to [Efficiently Stress Test Pod Memory](https://www.pingcap.com/blog/how-to-efficiently-stress-test-pod-memory/) and also there is a blog explaining  [Resource limiting CPU and Memory in Kubernetes](https://blog.vikki.in/resource-limiting-cpu-and-memory-in-kubernetes/) which can help you.

Comment: @Vasu Youth: Let me know if this resolves your issue.